# nodejs - issue with accessing the application remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, node.js

I am running nodejs application on my server with the link:

`http://localhost:3000`

Now I want to access this application remotely from anywhere. So i added 3000 to be allowed port in the server firewall (both TCP and UDP). But i cannot access this remotely from my system for example with the following link:

`http://server-ip-address:3000`

In the browser i am getting the following error in the console:
`GET http://server-ip-address:3000 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Am I missing something? Is there any other thing to be configured to access my application remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the application is bound to some real addresses, not only locahost. `netstat -an | findstr 3000`. If it's bound only to a `127.0.0.1`, this would be the root cause.